# Doesn't show a float that has a formula when I execute

Tags: c

I have a formula for the imc float but when I execute, it show 0.0 (in bold in the execution at the end)
I can't find my error. pls help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  float poids, taille, imc; // translate as weight, height, imc
  char reponse; // translate as response

do
{
  printf("\nTapez le poids en kg et la taille en metre "); // translate as Enter the weight in kg and the height in meter
  scanf("%f%f", &poids, &taille); 
  
  imc = poids / (taille * taille); // translate as imc = weight / (height * height)

  printf("L'usager pese %.1f kg, mesure %.2f metre et son imc est de %.1f\n ", poids, taille, imc); // translate as User weighs %.1f kg, measures %.2f meter and his BMI is %.1f

  if(imc < 18.5)

    printf("MAIGREUR, RISQUE ELEVE A ACCRU\n");

  else
    if(imc < 25)

      printf("POIDS NORMAL, RISQUE FAIBLE\n");

    else
      if(imc < 30)

        printf("EMBONPOINT, RISQUE ELEVE\n");

      else
        printf("OBESITE, RISQUE TRES ELEVE\n");

   printf("\nVoulez-vous continuer (o/n) ");
      scanf(" %c", &reponse);
    }while(reponse == 'o' || reponse == 'O');

    
  return 0;
}
```

Execution:

make -s
 ./main

Tapez le poids en kg et la taille en metre 75 130
L'usager pese 75.0 kg, mesure 130.00 metre et son imc est de **0.0**

MAIGREUR, RISQUE ELEVE A ACCRU

Voulez-vous continuer (o/n)

Comment: 75.0 / ( 130.0 * 130.0 ) = 0.004 : .1f => 0.0 Displayed result appears just fine. But 130 meters tall???? Isn't that a bit much?

Comment: You need to add extra `{` to your `if` and `else` blocks. Indentation doesn't indicate the body of an if, you must use braces for that.

Comment: @joshpoley Formatting and indentation can of course be improved in this question, but `if` or `else` with just a single following statement does not require braces. This is more a question of style.

Comment: If the answer helped and fixed your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is behaving correctly and the formula is correct as well as far as I can tell.

It just so happens that people having a height of 130 **meters** and a weight of 75 kg can indeed be considered to be *very* skinny, thus having a *very* low BMI.

The result turns out to be something around 0.004, which you format as 0.0.

I guess you wanted to enter the height in centimeters, which would require an extra step to divide the height by 100. This leads to a result of roughly 44. Still not a very healthy, but it does qualify as an actual human being ;)

Comment: I'm such an idiot! Haha I meant to say 1.30 meter so you're right, it was too much for the decimal I wanted..